# Can not find logback.xml in resources folder

Tags: java, logging, slf4j, logback

i'm trying to use logback in my project but there is some problem . when i run my code it gives me this:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/mostafa/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.2/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/mostafa/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.1/logback-classic-1.1.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.project.Test).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

my logback.xml is under `resources` folder:

```
$ tree sample

|-- pom.xml
`-- src
    `-- main
        |-- java
        |  
        |-- resources
        |   `-- logback.xml
```

and my project structure is :

[image]

Comment: What maven dependencies have you declared?

Comment: thank you @JamesB , i have added `org.slf4j` & `h.qos.logback`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you carefully read the error messge provided, you will notice that your problem is multiple bindings of sfl4j on your build path. You included sfl4j-log4j and logback-classic artifacts. Since logback-classic already contains native implementation of sfl4j and also automatically adds sfl4j jar to your project you end up having mutiple sf4j's in your build path. Simply make up your mind and choose only one logging framework and remove another one from your dependencies.

So if you choose logback-classic your Maven dependencies will look like this:

```
<dependency> 
  <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
  <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

If you choose log4j then make it look like this

```
<dependency> 
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.2</version>
</dependency>
```

But don't include both!

From [sfl4j manual](http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html):

> If you wish to use logback-classic as the underlying logging
>   framework, all you need to do is to declare
>   "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic" as a dependency in your pom.xml file
>   as shown below. In addition to logback-classic-1.0.13.jar, this will
>   pull slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar as well as logback-core-1.0.13.jar into your
>   project. Note that explicitly declaring a dependency on
>   logback-core-1.0.13 or slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar is not wrong and may be
>   necessary to impose the correct version of said artifacts by virtue of
>   Maven's "nearest definition" dependency mediation rule

Comment: could downvoters please explain where came the downvotes from? I would greatly appreciate that downvoters at least leave a comment under answer explaining their reasoning.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using cassandra or anythings else that may add the log4j artifact to your library?

If you add cassandra-all artifact to dependency and since the cassandra used log4j as the the SLF4J backend for self logging , it import slf4j-log4j12.jar

You can edit pom.xml like this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cassandra</groupId>
        <artifactId>cassandra-all</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

also read following link:

http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings

Comment: Usually the cassandra add slf4j-log4j12.jar and log4j.jar to the classpath.in error of above question also refers to these two files... . ;)